# make two divs float right and Overlap?

Tags: html, dom, css

can some one please tell me how can i make this two divs Overlap instead of being side by side

## hc_menu & #hc_show_hide

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnEaA/)
and this is the
code :
css :

```
   .chart_scroll{  height: 100%;}
    #hc_hover{height:100%;width: 25%; float: right;}
    #hc_menu{height:400px ;background-color: Black;opacity:0.4;margin:50px 0px 50px 20px;width:125px ; float:right;}
    #hc_show_hide{height:500px ; width: 15% ;float:right ; background:red;}
```

html :

```
 <div class="chart_scroll" runat="server" id="pnlCharts">
              <div id="hc_hover" >
              <div id="hc_show_hide"></div>
                <div id="hc_menu">
                    
                </div>
              </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *interact*?

Comment: Overlap? So they're on top of each other?

Comment: thanks @MetalFrog excuse my bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean overlap, then you'll need to set `position:absolute` and adjust your `z-index` to determine which one is on top.

There's some changes to your code, so here's the updated CSS, and [a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YnEaA/5/):

```
 .chart_scroll{  height: 100%;} 
#hc_hover{height:100%;width: 25%; float: right; position:relative; /* Keeps the children inside of its boundry */}
        #hc_menu{height:400px ;background-color: Black;opacity:0.4;margin:50px 0px 50px 20px;width:125px ; float:right; position:absolute;  right:0; /* lets it occupy the same space, aligned to the right */  z-index:50 /* puts this one on top */ }
        #hc_show_hide{height:500px ; width: 15% ;float:right ; background:red;  position:absolute; right:0; /* lets it occupy the same space, aligned to the right */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get them to overlap by using `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 0):

```
.chart_scroll{ width: 100%;}
#hc_menu, #hc_show_hide{width: 100px; height: 100px; float: right;  }
#hc_menu{background: blue; z-index: 1; position: relative; left: 10px; top: 10px;}
#hc_show_hide{background:red;}


<div class="chart_scroll" runat="server" id="pnlCharts">
    <div id="hc_hover" >
            <div id="hc_show_hide"></div>
            <div id="hc_menu"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the code above, blue will always be friend-zoned by red.  lol@mattytomo